# empty-cells on iPad browser

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, ipad-3

I have a table in a webpage that sometimes has empty cells. When viewed on my Firefox browser on my laptop it draws the border of those cells even if they are empty. When I view it on my iPad3 Safari browser it does not.

I discovered CSS `empty-cells:show` which I thought might be the solution, although the doc did suggest that `show` was the default. I thought perhaps the iPad browser could have a different default, so I tried it, but it made no difference.

Does the Safari browser on the iPad3 pay any attention to CSS `empty-cells:show`? Is there something else I should be doing to have borders round my empty cells? I have no access to the html in this case, so I can't add a `&nbsp;` into the empty cells to make them non-empty, so I need a CSS solution (or confirmation that there is no CSS solution).

```css
table {
    empty-cells: show;
}
td {
    border-bottom:  1px blue inset;
    border-left:    1px blue inset;
    border-spacing: 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>test data</td>
          <td>more data</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>after the empty cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test data</td>
          <td>more data</td>
          <td>and more</td>
          <td>after the empty cell</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you include the code for your table as well as the CSS pertaining to that table (including the empty-cells declaration)?

Comment: Added code as requested. Interestingly when I view THIS page via my iPad, it displays correctly and yet the same html and CSS outside of SO does not. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following property to your table.
border-collapse: collapse;
This will draw the border for all cells even if they are empty. Should work on Safari too.

```
table {
    empty-cells: show;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    border-bottom:  1px blue inset;
    border-left:    1px blue inset;
   border-spacing: 1px 1px;
}
```